# Unknown paymentMethodNonce on Braintree

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, braintree

Hello I try to set up a braintree payement on my website but I have an error when i create my Transaction sale : Unknown paymentMethodNonce. I generate a client token like an example from Braintree support (They sand me a mail with an example) :

```
<?php
require_once("../lib/Braintree.php");
$clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate(); ?>
...
<script>
var clientToken = "<?php echo $clientToken; ?>";
braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
        container: "payment-form"
    });
</script>
```

And on my checkout page :

```
require_once("../lib/Braintree.php");

$nonce = $_POST["payment_method_nonce"];

$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale([
    'amount' => "100",
    'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonce,
    'options' => [
        'submitForSettlement' => True
    ]
]);
```

I try to remove configuration line, it's work but the account merchant is not mine and if I set up the account in sale with :

```
    'merchantAccountId' => 'MyAccount',
```

or to configure before :

```
Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('xxx');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('xxx');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('xxxxx');
```

But I have an error : Exception need to be catch .

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work for Braintree.</sub>

The error you are getting suggests the `payment_method_nonce` is not reaching your server. Make sure you have a form like this in your client:

```
<form id="checkout" method="post" action="/checkout">
  <div id="payment-form"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Pay $10">
</form>
```

You need to configure your application with the `Braintree_Configuration::environment`, `merchantId`, `publicKey`, and `privateKey`. You would only pass in `merchantAccountId` with a `Braintree_Transaction::sale` if you want to use a merchant account that is not your default account.

If you are still having trouble, please continue working with [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com).